# Passing Complex Type with Array Of String to WEB API

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

I've searched through all the web about this i just wanted to make sure if i'm doing something wrong or not.

I'm trying to create a backend RESTful API service for a blogging web application. Let me explain the structure a little bit. I've a controller called "FilesController" which is an API controller client will make a PUT request to upload file(s) to the server and the server will return an uploadinfo for the client to use later while making a create request for the blog with the uploaded images. So the classes i need for this kinda simple scenario are "UploadInfo" and "BlogAPIModel" ;

UploadInfo

```
public class UploadInfo
{
    public string [] UploadedFileNames { get; set; }
}
```

BlogAPIModel

```
public class BlogAPIModel
{
    public string BlogTitle{ get; set; }

    UploadInfo UploadedData { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my controller codes:

FilesController:

```
public class FilesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadTempFile()
    {
        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MyFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try
        {
            // Read the form data.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            var uploadedFiles = new UploadInfo();

            var listOffileNames = new List<string>();

            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                listOffileNames.Add(file.LocalFileName);
            }

            uploadedFiles.UploadedFileNames = listOffileNames.ToArray();


            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, uploadedFiles);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
}
```

BlogsController:

```
public class BlogsController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateBlog(BlogAPIModel model) 
    {

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

}
```

And the Json Request Example I'm using while calling the "CreateBlog" method is as follows;

```
{
 "BlogTitle" : "Sample Blog Title", 
 "UploadedData" : { "UploadedFileNames" : ["samplepath1", "samplepath2"]}
}
```

I've tried everything i know but when i debug the requests "BlogTitle" field comes whatever i send from the client but "UploadedData" is always null it is not getting binded.

Do i have to write some kind of CustomModelBinder for this ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried defining UploadedFileNames as a `List<String>` instead of an array? Have you tried decorating model with `[FromBody]` as in `[FromBody]BlogJsonModel model`?

Comment: ı've tried both your suggestions no luck..

Comment: What does the HTTP request look like in Fiddler? Is the data in the body or the header? Is it formed properly? What you've laid out above should deserialize without any trouble, so I suspect something isn't formed properly, but you'll need to do more debugging to find what it is.